# Negotiate an access token from another registered app

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce

By testing [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow for Web App Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) in Salesforce, I've found a way to negotiate an access token by doing something somewhat weird.

Here is the scenario.

I've create two accounts :

- phdezann+user01-mbpt@force.com
- phdezann+user02-8wl6@force.com

With the second account, I've created an `New Connected App` and enabled `Enable OAuth Settings` and got a pair of clientId and secretId, part of the OAuth protocol.

Then, I've requested an authorization code by going to :

`https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id_of_user02_instance>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&response_type=code`

Here, *and this is the interesting part*, I logged in with the *user01* and managed to get an authorization code in the callback.

And finally, I've tried to convert that authorization code to an access token :

```
curl \
  --location \
  --request POST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
  --data-urlencode 'code=<authorization_code_from_user01>' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=<client_id_of_user02_instance>' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<client_secret_of_user02_instance>' \
  --data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080'
```

And, it worked. I got :

```
{
  "access_token": "00D2X00000....",
  "signature": "CSfC0khkT7...",
  "scope": "api",
  "instance_url": "https://eu13.salesforce.com",
  "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D2X000003IgQFUA0/0052X00000AP6AdQAL",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "issued_at": "1596728532049"
}
```

I really don't get how this is possible, I surely miss something here.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design and it's an OAuth2 thing, not really Salesforce thing.
If you would be making a mobile app or some amazing integration with your website - it's impractical to ask every admin to generate the app, paste keys to your mobile app and distribute to users... You'd ship your app with one pair of keys you control and then the end users decide if they trust you, want to proceed, are comfortable with the level of access you are requesting...

You can paste your keys to https://openidconnect.herokuapp.com/
or use it as is and get to your orgs.

See also https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/213666/799 and  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/70489/799